# How to use Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate an external class?

Tags: vb.net, instantiation, late-binding

I have an application where I want to instantiate a class that is completely outside the application, perhaps written at a later date by a third party.  So the class cannot be known, but the interfaces in the class are known.  So I want to use late binding.

In my code (VB.NET), I have the following:

```
Dim a As Object
a = Activator.CreateInstance("MyNameSpace.CustomClass", "")
MsgBox(a.Name)
```

I get an exception at the second line:  `Could not load file or assembly 'MyNameSpace.CustomClass' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` even though the assembly is in the same folder as the executable.  I can't use Type.GetType() because the type is not known to the calling assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [CreateInstanceFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstancefrom.aspx) method.

```
    var typeReference = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(assemblyPath, 
                                                       fullyQualifiedClassName);
```

But, for me, MEF would be a better solution as you can bind the Import/Export on the interface.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try after the new year.  Please explain, what is MEF?

Comment: Managed Extensibilty Framework  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: Awesome, thanks, but the solution targets .NET 3.5, so MEF is not an option.

Comment: I have used MEF with 3.5 you can get the assemblies on CodePlex http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/40606